# How do i keep the same random values after the ValueError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and coding in general, so this would probably sound dumb, and the code is most likely inefficient.

This is an extremely simple multiplication math game with 2 random variables between 0 and 10.

If the user leaves the variable "p" blank or types in anything other than an integer, after

displaying the message, how can i return the same random values without changing the entire equation?
Here's the code:

```
from random import*

while True:
    try:
    
        a = randint(0,10)
        b = randint(0,10)

        print(a, "*", b, "=", end=" ")
        p = int(input())

        if (a * b == p):
            print("Correct!")
            print("Try again?:", end="")
            redo = input()
        
            while redo == "":
                print("Please type in 'Yes' or 'No'")
                redo = input()
            
            if redo.lower() == "no":
                break
            
            elif redo.lower() == ("Yes", "Ok"):
                print(end="")
    
        elif (a * b != p):
            print("Incorrect!", "The correct result is: ", a*b)
            print("Try again?: ", end="")
            redo = input()
        
            while redo == "":
                print("Please type in 'Yes' or 'No'")
                redo = input()
            
            if redo.lower() == "no":
                break
            
            elif redo.lower() == ("Yes", "Ok"):
                print(end="")
    except ValueError:
        print("please enter in a vaild integer")
        pass
```

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: Put the loop with `try/except` just around the lines that ask for input, not the entire quiz.